# syntax error in python while checking for greater than symbol

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am getting syntax error in the below piece of code in python. Can someone please help me to know where I did the mistake. I am new to python.

```
X = lambda cus['id'],cus['maxamt']: \
       df1_test.TXNID[(df1_test['CUSTOMERID'] == cus['id'])\
      &(df1_test['CREDITAMT'] > cus['maxamt'])]
```

Thanks for your responses. Here I have a small array with all distinct values of of CUSTOMERID (1st column) and crresponding maximum CREDITAMT (2nd column). df1_test is a bigger dataframe with many columns in it.

I am trying to find the all the records of the df1_test dataset where the CREDITAMT of the customer is greater that the maximum value of the particular customer (The maximum credit amount and distinct customer id I can get from the smaller array)

Here is what I have tried. But it gives me error that " too many indices for array".

I did not want to use a for loop for the problem as the data is huge.

Can someone please help me.

My actual piece of code is:

```
X = sorted(cus_np,key=lambda x: \
         df1_test.TXNID[(df1_test['CUSTOMERID']==x[:,0])\
       &(df1_test['CREDITAMT'] > x[:,1])])
```

Thanks for the respose. Please see the example of my data:

```
import pandas as pd

small_distinct_array=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4],'max':[200,500,800,400]})

bigger_all_array=pd.DataFrame({'custid':[1,3,4,3,1,1,2,2,3,4],'amt':[300,400,800,300,900,700,500,700,400,500]})
```

I am trying to get the 'custid' values of the bigger_all_array where the corresponding 'amt' value is greater than the max field of small_distinct_array of the same customerid.

Comment: My goodness, why do you have all of that in a lambda

Comment: You should include the full error message when asking for help.

Comment: Please include an example of your "array" (which apparently is a pandas DataFrame) with column headers.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have column accesses in parameter names. `cus['id']` and `cus['maxamt']` are illegal. Just pass `cus` alone. Most likely you have more problems with this cumbersome piece of code, but at lest you'll get rid of the syntax error.

Comment: Hi DYZ, my aplogy for the edit in your comment. I was supposed to edit my question.

Answer (score -1):

`&` is a bitwise operator. Use `and` in place of `&`.

Comment: In Pandas, `&` is overloaded to act as a vectorized boolean `and`.

Comment: What Pandas? Did you mention that?

Comment: The OP uses Pandas dataframes.